# How to avoid posting empty string in HTTP POST method in C# .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, swagger

This is my `AddQuoteDto`:

```cs
public class AddQuoteDto
{
    
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Quote is required")]
    public string? Quote { get; set; } 

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Author is required")]
    public string? Author { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Tags are required")]
    public string? Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I run http post method on Swagger I get default object as below

```json
{
  "quote": "string",
  "author": "string",
  "tags": "string"
}
```

and hence it gets posted in the same form.

I've tried the following which both did not work.

```
public string? Quote { get; set; } 

public string? Quote { get; set; } = string.Empty;
```

Please suggest a way how I can tackle this situation.

Comment: You want to update the default sample that is displayed? Or what exactly is it you want to achieve? You can easily configure the example if you enable/ export XML documentation, configure Swagger to read the XML file for that assembly and use `<example>myValue</example>` in the XML comment for a property.

Comment: This is working as expected, Swagger creates a dummy json object and assigns the  "string" to string properties.

Comment: @MartinStaufcik how do I make it not post to my database is same way do i have to put server side validations? is there any other way I can stop that dummy json object to get posted directly?

Comment: You cannot prevent making requests to your API from Swagger, if that is what you are concerned about. You can add server side validations to the API endpoint. For example add some sort of ID into the request and validate that the user can make a request with this ID. It can be an ID of the account, project, or other entity that the quote entity references and is related to.

Comment: The question boils down to authentication and authorization of the POST request. One way is to use JWT Bearer tokens. There is quite a lot of articles about this topic available.

Comment: It would be relatively straightforward to make your server-side validation reject the dummy data... as long as an author named string didn't actually just say "string".